# Where does Subaru Impreza 2008 fuel filter lies?

Tags: subaru, impreza, fuel-filter

I am unable to locate the fuel filter in my 2008 Subaru Impreza, because I want to replace it?

Where does it lie?

Answer (score 1):

On that model the fuel filter is part of the fuel pump in the gas tank.

[image]